# Can't run Vue2 js projects

Tags: vuejs2

I am unable to run any vue projects\samples that I get from github or elsewhere.

I get this message or similar on every project I try.
I download a project. Run "npm i", and then run "npm run dev"

example project:
https://github.com/skyronic/vue-spa

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
at Function.listen (C:\vue-spa-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\vue-spa-master\build\dev-server.js:84:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-spa@1.0.0 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-spa@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\*USER*\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-23T20_54_53_970Z-debug.log
```

Comment: That error means that port 8080 is already being used by another process. You'll either need to end that process or specify a different port.

Comment: @thanksd Thank you! It seems obvious now what EADDRINUSE means.